# how to convert string date in required format in react

Tags: reactjs, date-formatting

```
let date =  "14-11-2021 10:11:20";
let required = "11-14-2021 10:11:20";
//convert [DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS] => [MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS]
```

Answer (score 0):

install package moment by "npm install --save moment"

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Moment from 'moment';
 
class App extends Component {
constructor() {
this.state = {
      FormatDMY: Moment("1994-08-11").format('DD-MM-YYYY'),
      FormatMDY: Moment("1994-07-01").format('MM-DD-YYYY')
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p> DMY Format: { this.state.FormatDMY } </p>
        <p> MDY Format: { this.state.FormatMDY } </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Output will be

DMY Format: 11-08-1994

MDY Format: 08-11-1994

OR

If you want the time field also then use

```
import { format } from "date-fns";

var actualDate = new Date("2021-01-05 11:14:33");
var formattedDate = format(actualDate, "MMMM do, yyyy H:mma");
console.log(formattedDate);
```

Comment: but given date format is ("14-11-2021 10:11:20");
moment("14-11-2021 10:11:20") return invalid date

Comment: Can you please try using that date-fns module

Comment: date-fns return invalid date with this format


import { format, parse } from 'date-fns'
const formattedDate = format(parse('15-10-2020 14:00:00'), 'MM/DD/YYYY');